# file_get_html & str_get_html with cURL are getting part of a page

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

This is a really weird situation that I can't explain.
I use `simple HTML DOM` and am trying to get the full code of this page:

```
http://ronilocks.com/
```

The thing is, I'm getting only part of what's actually on the page. 
For instance: look at the page source code and see all the script tags that are in the `plugins` folder. There are quite a few.
When I check the same with the string I get back from `simple HTML DOM` none of them  are there. Only `wp-rocket`.

(I used a clean `file_get_html()` and a `file_get_contents()` too and got the same result)

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Edit: Is it possible that `wp-rocket` (installed on the page being scrapped) knows that the page is being scrapped and shows something different?

Comment: Please show what code produces this.

Comment: There's not much to show :)
Something like this is one option:
dd(file_get_contents("http://ronilocks.com/")); (the dd is like var_dump in Laravel)

Comment: In many cases, some contents are loaded by js because they are 'dynamic'. So these 'dynamic' contents may not be fixed in html codes.

Comment: Try using curl and set the user-agent header to mozilla.

Comment: @Acepcs The content I don't see is not generated with JS, it exists in the source code

Comment: @pguardiario using cURL with a Mozilla user-agent doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://ronilocks.com/');
echo count($html->find('a'));
// 425
```

I get 425. This looks right to me.

Comment: Look for "script" or "link" instead of "a" and then loop through them and print them out. Now go to the actual site's source code and look for scripts with the word "plugins" in them. or look for the sentence "<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v7.0.3 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->" in the response like it exists in the actual site.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you have a separate question so you should edit or post a new question. Like "why can't simple html dom find this script/link?"

Comment: I edited the question a bit. I hope it's more clear now. Thanks